# How to play AV1 videos on Ubuntu 16.04.5

Tags: video, codecs, video-player, video-conversion, av1

In both [totem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer1.0/+bug/1789717) and [vlc](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/1789715), I cannot play [AV1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV1) videos. Sample videos can be downloaded [here](https://www.elecard.com/videos).

How can I watch AV1 videos on Ubuntu 16.04.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest version (not the one in the default repositories) of [mpv](https://mpv.io/) will handle it. v0.29.0 works.

Answer (score 2):

VLC supports decoding AV1 streams since 3.0.4.

You can install the latest VLC is via snaps:

```
sudo snap install vlc
```